# How to give same hostname to multiple devices in a zeroconf network?

Tags: networking, zeroconf, netbios, avahi

How to give same hostname to multiple devices in a zeroconf network , Is it even possible ?

Is it even locally possible to create aliases of the same name lets say project.local on one machine to its own webpage.

To make it clear when on one machine if we type in project.local it goes to its own webpage and when we do the same on another machine we get the webpage for that device not forgetting both are in the same network.

Any Views.

Comment: Can't you use localhost here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now do realize that its simply not possible to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that the web page is hosted on the same machine as the server.  If that is the case you can just type localhost in the browser, rather than using zeroconf.  If you do need to use zeroconf, i do not think it will work, if all the host are connected to the same network you will get multiple replies to the "typa A" zeroconf query.  If they are not connected to the same newtwowk, then it should work.

Comment: Is it possible that all the machines in a zeroconf network be addressed by a common name from a direct connection i.e lan cable as to ,to whichever device i connect physically .Lets say device 1,2,3.I connect to device 1 through a LAN cable access the page through myname.local, keeping the network alive ,unplug it from the first device and into the second and then address the second device by myname.local